# Gradle build fails. Trying to add sign to application using gradle.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to create 'property' and assign file name "gradle.properties to the same for signing my android application. For some reason it cannot find the file. It is present in the 'C:\Users\'username'\Reader_Mobile_App\ \Reader_Mobile_App\app' directory. The error says 'Could not find property "gradle.properties" on project ':app''.
I am new to android development and will really appreciate any input.

Thanks!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("gradle.properties"))))
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'release'
            keyPassword props['keystore.password']
            storeFile file(props['keystore'])
            storePassword props['keystore.password']
        }
        debug {
            keyAlias 'debug'
            keyPassword props['keystore.password']
            storeFile file(props['keystore'])
            storePassword props['keystore.password']
        }
    }

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.troxler.version1p1'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile files('libs/junit-4.7.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me share how I do it in my case:

```
def props = new Properties()
def propsFile = rootProject.file('app/gradle.properties')
props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
```

I saved my file inside:

```
APPNAME/app
```

So, it seems that you also have add it to "app" folder... So, I think my code may work to you as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input.Just tried creating a folder app and including the path to the file inside it but it throws the same error: ' could not find property 'app/gradle.properties' on project :app'.

Comment: Sorry to hear that... Please, share the complete path of you Application and also the path of the properties file. In my case, my file is in the same folder of build.gradle file (in other words, both are in the same app folder).

Comment: Path for application 'app'= C:\Users\'username'\Reader_Mobile_App\ Reader_Mobile_App\Beta V1\                                                                                 Path for file: 'C:\Users\'username'\Reader_Mobile_App\Reader_Mobile_App\Beta V1\app\app'

Comment: @user3443084 Sorry for the additional request... share the path of the build gradle file (where you add the code above)

Comment: Sure. Thank you for taking time to look into this.                                                     Path to build file is: C:\Users\'Username'\Reader_Mobile_App\Reader_Mobile_App\Beta V1\app

Comment: @user3443084 Ok. No problem. Try to move the properties file from "C:\Users\'username'\Reader_Mobile_App\Reader_Mobile_App\Beta V1\app\app" to "C:\Users\'username'\Reader_Mobile_App\Reader_Mobile_App\Beta V1\app"

Comment: yes, originally that was the file location and it still threw error. For now I have removed the reference to 'Properties' and directly assigned the values.

Comment: like this:                                                                                                       android {
       signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias "release"
            keyPassword "password"
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry to hear that... For some reason, build script is not finding the file.. So, some path is wrong... Sorry for not help you more...

Comment: np! Thank you for trying.